# how to convert html to pdf using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, wiki-pages

I have a SharePoint list on which a workflow is attached that adds the list item to a HTML page. I want to convert this html page to pdf and save it on click of a button through javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There are open source / third party libraries to help with this. Perhaps check out [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) or [PDFMake](http://pdfmake.org/#/).

Answer (score 0):

Content inside a `<div class='html-content'>....</div>` can be downloaded as pdf with styles using **jspdf** & **html2canvas**.

You need to refer both js libraries,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

Then call below function,

```
//Create PDf from HTML...
function CreatePDFfromHTML() {
    var HTML_Width = $(".html-content").width();
    var HTML_Height = $(".html-content").height();
    var top_left_margin = 15;
    var PDF_Width = HTML_Width + (top_left_margin * 2);
    var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width * 1.5) + (top_left_margin * 2);
    var canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;
    var canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;

    var totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(HTML_Height / PDF_Height) - 1;

    html2canvas($(".html-content")[0]).then(function (canvas) {
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin, canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);
        for (var i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) { 
            pdf.addPage(PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, -(PDF_Height*i)+(top_left_margin*4),canvas_image_width,canvas_image_height);
        }
        pdf.save("Your_PDF_Name.pdf");
        $(".html-content").hide();
    });
}
```

Ref: [pdf genration from html canvas and jspdf](https://www.freakyjolly.com/jspdf-multipage-example-generate-multipage-pdf-using-single-canvas-of-html-document-using-jspdf/).

Comment: Same issue is there, I didn't see the complete PDF. I see blank black pages in IE. And also I didn't see the clear PDF.